# Git Command To Display Branch I Branched From

Tags: git

If the branch I have checked out is called 'version-2' and I run these commands to create a branch off of that branch:

```
git branch  user-story-999
git checkout user-story-999
```

Is there a git command to show the branch (version-2) which I originally branched off of?

Comment: Short answer is **no, not in git**. Other softwares might keep track of this, but not git itself.

Comment: One reason for this is : the "source" branch you branched off of is not rock solid. It might move, or cease to exist. Branches are pointing at commits, not at other branches. If you create a *branch off of another branch*, you in fact *branch off of the commit* it points to at the moment. No special link between these two branches is kept anywhere in git.

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks for the information. That makes sense.